# Trouble Creating Directories with mkdir

Tags: ruby, mkdir

New to Ruby, probably something silly

Trying to make a directory in order to store files in it. Here's my code to do so

```
def generateParsedEmailFile
    apath = File.expand_path($textFile)
    filepath = Pathname.new(apath + '/' + @subject + ' ' + @date)
    if filepath.exist?
        filepath = Pathname.new(filepath+ '.1')
    end
    directory = Dir.mkdir (filepath)
    Dir.chdir directory
    emailText = File.new("emailtext.txt", "w+")
    emailText.write(self.generateText)
    emailText.close
    for attachment in @attachments
        self.generateAttachment(attachment,directory)
    end
end
```

Here's the error that I get

```
My-Name-MacBook-2:emails myname$ ruby etext.rb email4.txt
etext.rb:196:in `mkdir': Not a directory - /Users/anthonydreessen/Developer/Ruby/emails/email4.txt/Re: Make it Brief Report Wed 8 May 2013 (Errno::ENOTDIR)
    from etext.rb:196:in `generateParsedEmailFile'
    from etext.rb:235:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does `$textFile` really need to be a global variable? That's usually not necessary.

Comment: example folder name you expected ?

Comment: what are the values of your variables?  From the error, it looks like  apath = "/Users/myname/Developer/Ruby/emails/email4.txt", subject = "CORRECT SUBJECT" and date = "CORRECT DATE"

Comment: @datguy Oh I was just "blurring" them out because someone yelled at me for privacy stuff one time one here. I've updated the actual printout of the error

Comment: It's always good to use dummy data.

Comment: is email4.txt a file?  It looks like you are trying to create a directory with a file as part of the pathname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to recreate the error - it looks like email4.txt is a regular file, not a directory, so you can't use it as part of your directory path.

Answer (score 2):

If you switched to `mkdir_p` and get the same error, perhaps one of the parents named in `'/Users/anthonydreessen/Developer/Ruby/emails/email4.txt/Re: Make it Brief Report Wed 8 May 2013'` already exists as a regular file and can't be treated like a directory. Probably that last one named `email.txt`

Comment: Oh wow... Thanks for the troubleshooting. That's an embarrassing problem

Comment: Happy to help. (Not to karma whore too much, but I'm a little confused why datguy gets the credit when my answer identifying the problem predates his by an hour.)

Comment: I saw that datguy has considerably less karma than you and he was helping out earlier as well. I sorta figured that when you have over 5K the points don't mean as much. I hope I have not erred.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but should be more specific about the files you're opening. Changing the current working directory is really messy as it changes it across the entire process and could screw up other parts of your application.

```
require 'fileutils'

def generate_parsed_email_file(text_file)
  path = File.expand_path("#{@subject} #{date}", text_file)

  while (File.exist?(path))
    path.sub!(/(\.\d+)?$/) do |m|
      ".#{m[1].to_i + 1}"
    end
  end

  directory = File.dirname(path)
  unless (File.exist?(directory))
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(directory)
  end

  File.open(path, "w+") do |email|
    emailText.write(self.generateText)
  end

  @attachments.each do |attachment|
    self.generateAttachment(attachment, directory)
  end
end
```

I've taken the liberty of making this example significantly more Ruby-like:

- Using mixed-case names in methods is highly irregular, and global variables are frowned on.
- It's extremely rare to see `for` used, `each` is much more flexible.
- The `File.open` method yields to a block if the file could be opened, and closes automatically when the block is done.
- The ".1" part has been extended to keep looping until it finds an un-used name.
- FileUtils is employed to makes sure the complete path is created.
- The global variable has been converted to an argument.

Comment: Nice. A couple further improvements to consider: no need for unless exists test to protect `mkdir_p`. Ruby 2 has [`File::write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-write) now for when you just want to dump a string into a file in one shot.

Comment: I am mistaken, the error occurs in File.open Let me see if I did something else wrong

Comment: Yeah you could probably just go ahead and let `mkdir_p` do nothing, that should be harmless enough.

Comment: @Pinwheeler You shouldn't get a `mkdir` error now, but if it's `File.open`, then I'm curious what the full message is.

Comment: @tadman it was a bad filepath. I was trying to open a directory inside a text file